# A way to reorder row IDs in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table from which I fetch rows always sorting by their ID. At some point I create an array with new ID order by which the rows should be fetched next time. What is the best way to switch the rows' IDs to match the new order? Or is there another way to do it?

Example:

```
ID col1 col2 ...
1  a    aa
2  b    bb
3  c    cc
```

Rows are fetched in that order. Now I wish the new order would be 2, 3 and 1, so I need to change the table to something like this:

```
ID col1 col2 ...
1  b    bb
2  c    ccc
3  a    aaa
```

The value of new IDs can chage to whatever as long as the desired order is preserved.

Comment: Is this `ID` also your primary key? If so, don't do this. Use a separate column named `Sequence` or similar for ordering.

Comment: Are you using php or another scripting language, or do you want to do this in pure MySQL? Also, agreed with RedFilter: primary keys should be permanent, insofar as possible.

Comment: Well this is the primary key, but I think can add a order column. I'm doing this in node.